# Updating SQL Server database with SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have a `DataTable` with new entries, and I want to add these to an existing database.

So I create a `SqlDataAdapter` and fill a second table with it, then I merge the two tables, and update the database, but nothing happens, the return value is 0, the database stays the same.

Here's my code:

```
DBManager.DBDestinationConnect(textBox10.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox7.Text, ref destinationConnection);
//DBManager is a Class, to connect with the database
CategoryAdapterBackup = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM " + tablename, destinationConnection);

CategoryTableBackup = new DataTable();
CategoryAdapterBackup.Fill(CategoryTableBackup);
CategoryTableBackup.Merge(SubTable);

//SubTable is the DataTable with the new entries
CategoryAdapterBackup.Update(CategoryTableBackup);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a problem discerning your intentions with this code. Why not simply use sqlbulkcopy on SubTable? That would append the contents of SubTable to the destination SQL table. If you are afraid of duplicates, then insert the contents of SubTable Table to a Temp in the DB and maybe use a Join to insert rows into the destination table where not exists row in destination table.

Comment: `sqlbulkcopy` was the way to go. I simply merged the 2 tables and wrote the difference to another table. This way I can use `sqlbulkcopy` without duplicates, and without using a Temp in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CategoryAdapterBackup.Flush()` or with `DBManager.Flush()`
also, could be a good idea replace `SELECT*FROM` by `SELECT * FROM` (with spaces)

Comment: The `SqlDataAdapter` has no definition for Flush, and the `DBManager` didn´t have on too, because it is my on Class with only contains two functions to connect with different Databases